# selectBooleanCheckbox updates the property in a a4j rerender

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-1.2

I'm on JSF 1.2 and am wondering about a behavior I'm seeing. My JSF page uses a4j:jsFunction to kick off a process and then uses a4j:poll to fetch the progress percentage. This process builds a list of objects, which each contains a list again. When the a4j:jsFunction call is finished, a a4j:outputPanel is rerendered. This panel contains a selectBooleanCheckbox which is bound to a boolean on objects in the second lists:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="validate" action="#{MigrationWizardValidateForm.validate}" reRender="validationResult, done"/>
...
<a4j:outputPanel id="validationResult">
    <ui:repeat value="#{MigrationWizardValidateForm.validationErrors}" var="validationError">
        <ui:repeat value="#{validationError.assignmentVisualisations}" var="assignmentVisualisation">
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{assignmentVisualisation.assignment.mainLocation}"
...
```

What I see is that the mainLocation is true when the process loads the object. It is true when the outer repeat gets its list. But when the selectBooleanCheckbox renders, it calls setMainLocation with false.

Why does it do that?

Comment: Looks like `assignmentVisualisation.assignment.mainLocation` starts with default `false` value and then is updated.

Comment: No. My problem is that it initially is true and the upon a4j rerender is set by JSF to false. Below is my logging: set true /
onadd true / onget true / set false / onget false / onget false / onget false. The initial set is the loading of the object, when added to the list it is still true, when the outer repeat gets the data it is true and then there suddenly is a set...

Comment: Again, looks like `assignmentVisualisation.assignment.mainLocation` default value is `false` (look if in your entity it has `true` as default value). Then, assuming `assignmentVisualisation` is a request managed bean and you simply create a new instance of `assignment` inside it, it will set `assignment.mainLocation` as `false`. If you want to maintain the state of this bean through instances, change the managed bean scope from request to session, or since you're using JSF 1.2 + RichFaces 3.x, you can keep it in request scope and add `@KeepAlive` to your managed bean class.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I understand. The bean already is request scoped with @org.ajax4jsf.model.KeepAlive. The ajax request correctly gets the list after poll several times. The constructor of the bean is only called once when the page is first loaded.

Comment: Not sure about JSF 1.2, but in early Mojarra 2.x versions, nested `<ui:repeat>` have had a lot of state saving related problems with input components. Try `<c:forEach>` and/or `<a4j:repeat>` instead. Even if it's just only the outer loop.

Comment: @BalusC: the a4j does not make a difference. The c version does not iterate over the collection at all (also not when using ${}) but it does nicely demonstrate the problem: the boolean stays true. <c:forEach items="${MigrationWizardValidateForm.validationErrors}" var="validationError">

Comment: Found the problem! It's the a4j:poll and a4j:jsFunction in the same form causing the problem. I've now put the progress in its own form and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

a4j:poll and a4j:jsFunction in the same form are causing the problem. Putting the poll to show the progress in a separate form solves it.